# Ejecutar una User Defined Function (String_SPLIT) desde un Stored Procedure. SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, funciones, stored-procedure

tengo una tabla 'entrevistas' en SQL que almacena, entre otros,  datos NVARCHAR en la columna 'id_cuenta', y datos tipo **NTEXT** en la columna 'respuesta' la cual se alimenta de una serie de preguntas y respuestas concatenadas divididas por el símbolo '|'.

Ya tengo una función que separa cadenas (funciona correctamente al ingresar texto plano), sus variables son (`@string NVARCHAR ,@simbolo CHAR(1)`); lo que estoy tratando de hacer (y no consigo) es que desde un **Stored Procedure** se busque en la tabla 'entrevistas' las respuestas que da la cuenta ###, luego que tome ese valor y a través de la función, me desglose una tabla con cada sección dividida por '|'. Esto es lo que tengo:

a) La función:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString] 
( 
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1) 
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(splitdata NVARCHAR(MAX) 
) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF @end = 0  
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1

        INSERT INTO @output (splitdata)  
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)) 
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)

    END 
    RETURN 
END
```

b)El procedimiento:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[respuestaSPLIT]
(                                               
@cuenta NVARCHAR(max),                  
@ans NVARCHAR(max)                      
)                                       
as                                      
    SELECT respuesta FROM [pruebaEDGE].[dbo].[entrevistas] WHERE [id_cuenta]= '@cuenta'
    set @ans = respuesta
    SELECT * FROM [dbo].[fnSplitString] (@ans,'|')
Go
```

c)la tabla:

```
`CREATE TABLE [dbo].[entrevistas](
    [id_entrevista] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [id_cuenta] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [tipo_entrevista] [int] NOT NULL,
    [numero_entrevistado] [int] NOT NULL,
    [nombre_entrevistado] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [respuesta] [ntext] NULL,
    [fecha_alta] [date] NULL,
    [id_usuario_alta] [int] NULL,
    [fecha_modificacion] [date] NULL,`
```

d)el error:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure respuestaSPLIT, Line 8 [Batch Start Line 0]
Invalid column name 'nombre_entrevistado'.
```

Comment: pues dice que no hay ninguna columna que se llame nombre_entrevistado

Comment: Por favor postea la definición de la tabla `entrevistas`

Comment: Efectivamente en la tabla `entrevistas` el sp está buscando el campo `nombre_entrevistado` que no existe

Comment: @PatricioMoracho No, ese no es el problema. La columna probablemente existe, simplemente la línea: `set @ans = nombre_entrevistado` no hace sentido porque no hay un `FROM` ni nada. Le pido al op que postee la definición de la tabla, porque dice que usa una columna `NTEXT`, que no va a funcionar

Comment: Si, ahora lo veo claro con la definición de los campos. Saludos

Comment: @Lamak En efecto, la columna existe, el error que ponen al respecto es porque estaba experimentando con la tabla y olvidé cambiar el nombre de la columna pero ambas existen.

Comment: El problema lo tienes como dice @Lamak al llenar la variable `@ans`, debieras hacerlo así `SELECT @ans = respuesta FROM [pruebaEDGE].[dbo].[entrevistas] WHERE [id_cuenta]= '@cuenta'`

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Aún hay un problema con ese código, porque está usando `'@cuenta'` como un string, debería ser: `SELECT @ans = respuesta FROM [pruebaEDGE].[dbo].[entrevistas] WHERE [id_cuenta]= @cuenta`. Aún así, si la columna es `ntext` este código se va a caer

Comment: @Lamak en la documentación de SQL aparece que NTEXT se convierte implicitamente a NVARCHAR

Comment: @EdgardHuerta entonces prueba el código que está posteado en el comentario

Comment: Ya... casi. Ya creó el procedimiento, gracias con eso. Pero creo que lo hice mal, porque ahora, cuando lo invoco, me pide que defina el parámetro @ans (la cadena que busco que parta la función), cosa que esperaba obtuviera desde el  primer SELECT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno, el procedimiento debe quedar de la siguiente forma:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[respuestaSPLIT]
(                                               
@cuenta NVARCHAR(max)                     
)                                       
as                                      
DECLARE @ans NVARCHAR(max);

SELECT @ans = respuesta 
FROM [pruebaEDGE].[dbo].[entrevistas] 
WHERE [id_cuenta]= @cuenta;

SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[fnSplitString] (@ans,'|');
```

De todas formas no entiendo para qué estás creando este sp en vez de simplemente usar la funcipón directamente

Comment: Gracias, quedó perfecto. El asunto es que la función no me permite ingresar consultas SQL, por eso necesitaba de una variable @ans que almacenara la respuesta.

Comment: @EdgardHuerta a qué te refieres que no permite ingresar consultas SQL?, no veo ningún problema la verdad

Comment: Me refiero a una instrucción para que busque la respuesta de acuerdo al cliente. Tal vez me faltó decir que estoy creando una interfaz en vba para excel y lo que quiero es poder recuperar las respuestas que se dieron rompiendo esa cadena. El problema surgió cuando corrí la función y en el parámetro @string no puede ser una instrucción de T-SQL, únicamente me permite ingresar cadenas de texto.